# Best way to force uniqueness of a 2-character field within a factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have country factory that looks something like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :country do 
    name { "Country_Name_#{rand(10000).to_s}#{('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.join.first(10)}" }
    alpha { ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.join.first(2) } 
  end
end
```

alpha is a 2 letter country code, for which I validate uniqueness.

```
validates :alpha,
  presence: true,
  uniqueness:true,
  length: {is: 2}
```

When running large tests, I often run into

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Alpha has already been taken
```

Particularly when creating child records

```
factory :state do 
  name { "State_Name_#{rand(10000).to_s}#{('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.join.first(10)}" }
  country
end
```

Is there a better way to construct my country factory to avoid duplicates? Or is there a better way to construct the state factory so that the belongs_to country is a mixture of new and existing records

## The Solution

For anyone else coming here with a similar issue, sequences are definitely the way to go (thanks born4new and Slicedpan).

In implementing this, I realized I had some other issues that were causing problems.

First, Database Cleaner was not running correctly, so that database was not being reset to a clean state between tests. Hence I was running into duplicates quite quickly.

I also found I needed to reset FactoryGirl sequences after each test. Otherwise, for long sequences, I was seeing `zx, zy, zz, a, b`, and the single characters were failing my validations.

```
#spec/rails_helper.rb
config.append_after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When things have to be unique, I tend to use sequences. For the country code, you'll need to enumerate the possible country codes. One way is below

```
sequence :country_code do |n|  
  i1 = n % 26
  i2 = n / 26
  chars = ('a'..'z').to_a
  "#{chars[i1]}#{chars[i2]}"
end
```

then in your factory you can simply do

```
factory :country do 
  name { "Country_Name_#{rand(10000).to_s}#{('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.join.first(10)}" }
  alpha { generate :country_code } 
end
```

Comment: thanks @slicedpan, this is a good idea. I had looked at sequences but my implementation was not as complete as yours. Do you know how/ when during a test factorygirl will restart the sequence? Is it for the entire duration of the test suite, or for a particular spec, or..? I still seemed to run into duplications

Comment: Should be for the entire suite as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

> When running large tests,

You have at most (might be a bit less) `26^2 = 676` possible combinations for alpha, so if `large tests` means more than that, there's no way around it.

For the sake of the argument, I'll suppose it's less than that.

You could start from 'AA' and 'increment' it like so:

> AB AC ... AZ BA BB BC ...etc

To do this, you could play with factory girl's sequences (using modulos and divisons):

```
sequence(:alpha) do |n|
  ('a'..'z').to_a[n / 26] + ('a'..'z').to_a[n % 26]
end
```

Comment: thanks @born4new. Do you know at what stage FactoryGirl will restart the sequence? Does it continue for the duration of the suite, or for a particular spec, or...?

Comment: I believe it is for the whole test suite. They are set once you load FactoryGirl (so I assume in your `rails_helper` file).

Answer (score 0):

This is less efficient than using sequences (since it requires a database read), but works well:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :country do 
    alpha do
      loop do
        possible_state = ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(2).join
        break possible_state unless Country.exists?(alpha: possible_state)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also note the use of `sample`.